# What is the name of this operation between sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Suppose we have a collection of sets $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$.
(To make it simple, we can assume these sets lie in some "universe set" $S$ and the index set $I$ is possibly finite.)

The union of these sets is defined as $\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i = \{a\in S | \exists i \colon a\in S_i\}$.

The intersection of these sets is defined as $\bigcap_{i\in I} S_i = \{a\in S | \forall i \colon a\in S_i\}$.

Similarly we can define the set operation $\mathbf{\{a\in S | \exists! i \colon a\in S_i\}}$. I've seen it a lot of times, but does this have an actual name?

It generalizes the symmetric difference between two sets, but the similarity stops there.

Comment: Are you using the symbols $\exists!$ for the quantifier "there exists a unique..."?

Comment: I have no immediate idea where this operation occur naturally. Do you have any example?

Comment: @BillWallis yes. It's the set of all the elements belonging to only one of the given sets.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe in this form is more recognizable? $\bigcup_i S_i \setminus \bigcup_{j\neq k}(S_j\cap S_k)$ It's the union of the sets where you cut out all the intersections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since symmetric difference of two sets is denoted by $A\triangle B,$ I suppose you could do something like $$\triangle_{i\in I}S_i.$$ I've never seen it before, but it seems natural enough.

That said, you should make sure to explicitly define it for your readers before using it extensively. It seems that [$n$-ary symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#n-ary_symmetric_difference) is usually defined quite differently.

---

If you want to be very technical, you could instead show this as $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(S_i\smallsetminus\left(\bigcup_{j\in I\smallsetminus\{i\}}S_j\right)\right),$$ but that seems like a pain.

---

**Added**: It might be better to go with $$!_{i\in I}S_i,$$ instead. It doesn't conflict with factorial notation or $n$-ary symmetric difference, and it's brief. I'm afraid I've been unable to find anything about a name for such an operation, though.

Comment: As you said it would create a conflict with symmetric difference so I would use another symbol if necessary. An easy way to describe it is also the following $\bigcup_i S_i \setminus \bigcup_{j\neq k}(S_j\cap S_k)$.

Comment: I saw that another name of symmetric difference is "disjunctive union", which is maybe what this operation really is. So I'd go with **disjunction** so it has the final "on" as uni**on** and intersecti**on**.

The symbol I'd use would be $⩌_{i\in I}S_i$ which combines the ! you suggested and the $\cup$.

It seems strange it doesn't have a name though.

Comment: The term "disjunction" typically refers to combining statements with the "or" connector, and (as such) is highly suggestive of $\bigcup.$

Comment: I like the "eyepatch" symbol, though. :-)

Comment: Actually you're right. What I had in mind was **distinction**.

Comment: I *really* like *that*.